# Slow SparQL query when joining two sets of URIs

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am checking a SparQL query which is running too slow on my system. Very much simplified, the query goes like this:

```
# The whole query takes ~20 seconds
SELECT ?baseUri_s1 {

    # This takes ~1 second and returns 3000 results
    { SELECT ?baseUri_s1 {
      # Here goes some more complex business logic
      ?baseUri_s1 myOntology:hasProperty1 'myProperty1'
    } }

    # This takes ~0.1 seconds and returns 1 result
    { SELECT ?baseUri_s2 {
      # Here goes some more complex business logic
      ?baseUri_s2 myOntology:hasProperty2 'myProperty2'
    } }

    FILTER (?baseUri_s1 = ?baseUri_s2)
}
```

So if the two inner selects take under 1 second each... Is it possible that joining a list of 3000 URIs and another list of one URI takes over 18 seconds? Am I missing something?

Comment: why are you using 2 subqueries instead of just using the same variable for both triple patterns? `SELECT ?s {

    
      ?s1 myOntology:hasProperty1 'myProperty1' .
  
      ?s1 myOntology:hasProperty2 'myProperty2'
    }` - but yes, if both subqueries are complex, it might take some time. The question is how much time each subquery already takes. Indeed ,we neither know your data nor the complex queries not the server on which you're running the triple store

Comment: The two subqueries take under a second each, and the whole thing will thus return in ~1.5 seconds if removing the "FILTER" line. The subqueries return 3000 and 1 result, so from that point on it's basically about joining both lists of URIs... and that last part alone takes 15 seconds.

Comment: Could you please peovide an example on FactForge?

Comment: what happens if you just return the same variable name in each subquery, i.e. don't use the filter?

Comment: Same thing happens, it still takes 18-20 seconds

Answer (score 1):

According to the SPARQL spec, each subselect will be executed independently. If the first subselect return 1'000 results and the second 300, the Cartesian product between the two datasets would be 300'000. Comparing 300'00 is likely to be much slower.

Why you don't simply execute the query as:

```
# The whole query takes ~20 seconds
SELECT ?baseUri_s1 {

    # Here goes some more complex business logic query 1
    ?baseUri_s myOntology:hasProperty1 'myProperty1'

    # Here goes some more complex business logic query 2
    ?baseUri_s myOntology:hasProperty2 'myProperty2'
}
```

Then you will eliminate the nasty Cartesian product between sub-queries without shared variables and the query optimizer may push some of the complex business logic optimizations earlier.